# Cannot get anchor tag to work correctly on accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an issue with an accordion I am using, in the HTML I have

```
<div class="expand"><a title="expand/collapse" href="#" style="display: block;">Working with Apple devices</a></div>
                    <div class="collapse">
                        <div class="accCntnt">
                            <p style="font-weight:normal; color:#333;">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and the css

```
.adCntnr .acco2 .expand a {
background: url(../images/rnd_plus_icon.png) no-repeat 0 4px;
padding-left: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
```

This ensures each title is clickable and has a round plus sign next to it like so - 
[image]

Everything was fine until I wanted to add an image link within the text.

After amending the text to add an image link like so -

```
<p style="font-weight:normal; color:#333;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<p> <a href="#" ><img src="LinkToButtonIcon"/></p>
```

I get this

[image]

I can understand why this is happening, the css is doing exactly what I have told it to do, I don't know how I can get around this and basically make the css not do anything to the A tag for my image link in the text - any help would be appreciated

Comment: post demo with all relevant code

Comment: As per your broken code all I can extract is that **CSS** is being written for default `<a>` inside `expand` class i.e. why it is creating that issue also you've missed to close the `<a>` within your `<p>` tag.

So all you've to do is close tags properly and write **CSS** for `<a>` tag inside of that `<p>` or using any `class` and reset all the pre-defined properties.

Comment: `<p> <a href="#" ><img src="LinkToButtonIcon"/></a></p>  ` check this

Comment: Thanks for the spot - I was using notepad and doing this freehand - I have now downloaded Komodo edit to stop simple errors like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `>` parent child css selector:

```
.adCntnr .acco2 .expand > a {
    /*the properties as is.*/
}
```

This will target only the anchors which is a direct child of `.expand` element.

```css
div > a{ color:orange;}
```

```html
<div>
<a href='#'>This is direct child of div. <p><a href='#'>This is a child too but not a direct one.</a></p></a>
</div>
```